# Countif on sheet with 700k rows freezes program

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, bigdata, countif

I currently have two lists. A list of "Grantors" in column A and the same list with duplicates removed in column B. I am trying to get a count of how many times a given Grantor is in Column A using countif however my list in Column A is over 700k rows. I am using 64bit excel but every time I run code to do this excel freezes and crashes.

Is there a way to do this in excel or do I need to take another approach like using a pivot table or creating tables in access?

I have written a few sub routines but this is the latest, got from another post on this forum.

```
Sub Countif()

  Dim lastrow As Long
  Dim rRange As Range
  Dim B As Long '< dummy variable to represent column B

  B = 2

  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False 'speed up processing by turning off screen updating
    .DisplayAlerts = False
  End With

  'set up a range to have formulas applied
  With Sheets(2)
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rRange = .Range(.Cells(2, B), .Cells(lastrow, B))
  End With

  'apply the formula to the range
  rRange.Formula = "=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$777363,C2)"
  'write back just the value to the range
  rRange.Value = rRange.Value

  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you have code then it's best to include it in your question.

Comment: How many unique values do you have?

Comment: I just remembered I don't have Excel on this computer, which makes it hard to check a few things. Have you tested this with just a few rows just to make sure the problem is the size, and that it works correctly in the first place? You could try turning calculations to manual before running (along with screenupdating like you do) and then back to automatic at the end

Comment: @TimWilliams 340k. What Im trying to do is get this count then do the same with two similar lists of Grantees then use that to determine who is buying and selling the most

Comment: @mock_blatt Yes I have tested it. I changed my range to 700  rows and it worked like it should.

Comment: Best I can do here is ~30sec (700k values, ~300k uniques) using arrays and a dictionary.  Hopefully we can re-open this and I'll post my code.

Comment: The good news is that if I am predicting Tim's method correctly, you can discard the RemoveDuplicates or AdvancedFilter  w/unique call to the second sheet because a unique list and associated count will be constructed in one operation.

Comment: @user10735198 - actually no ;-)  I'm not making any assumptions about the content of the list in ColB....

Comment: @TimWilliams, I thought the dictionary keys would be the unique list and the items the count. Need a custom transpose function to overcome the application.transpose limits but there are a few of those hanging around.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Sub Countif()

    Dim allVals, uniqueVals, i As Long, dict, v, dOut(), r As Long

     ''creating dummy data
'    With Sheet2.Range("A2:A700000")
'        .Formula = "=""VAL_"" & round(RAND()*340000,0)"
'        .Value = .Value
'    End With
'

    'get the raw data and unique values
    With Sheet2
        allVals = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
        uniqueVals = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With
    ReDim dOut(1 To UBound(uniqueVals, 1), 1 To 1) 'for counts...

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'map unique value to index
    For i = 1 To UBound(uniqueVals, 1)
        v = uniqueVals(i, 1)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then dict(v) = i
    Next i


    'loop over the main list and count each unique value in colB
    For i = 1 To UBound(allVals, 1)
        v = allVals(i, 1)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            If dict.exists(v) Then
                r = dict(v)
                dOut(r, 1) = dOut(r, 1) + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    'output the counts
    Sheet2.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(dOut, 1), 1).Value = dOut

End Sub
```

Runs in ~30sec with 700k values in A and 300k uniques in B

Answer (score 1):

... or maybe this.

> <sub>Caution: this overwrites the de-duplicated values in column A of the target worksheet.</sub>

```
Option Explicit

Sub countUnique()
    Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, dict As Object

    Debug.Print Timer

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare

    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        arr = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        dict.Item(arr(i, 1)) = dict.Item(arr(i, 1)) + 1
    Next i

    With Worksheets("sheet3")
        .Cells(2, "A").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = bigTranspose(dict.keys)
        .Cells(2, "B").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = bigTranspose(dict.items)
    End With

    Debug.Print Timer

End Sub

Function bigTranspose(arr1 As Variant)
    Dim t As Long
    ReDim arr2(LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1), 1 To 1)

    For t = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        arr2(t, 1) = arr1(t)
    Next t
    bigTranspose = arr2
End Function
```

42.64 seconds for 700K originals and 327K uniques on a Surface Pro tablet. This might be improved by turning off calculation and enableevents. Screenupdating really shouldn't be an issue.